# multiple threaded programs and os processes

Tags: java

I came across this statement in the OCA prep book written by Kathy Sierra. I assume when run my java program using my jvm , it run a single OS process. I guess the program that I run is executed by this process. If this is true , how can the java program use many OS processes?

> Multithreaded Java provides built-in language features and APIs that
>   allow programs to use many operating-system processes (hence, many
>   “cores”) at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

A process runs independently and isolated of other processes. It cannot directly access shared data in other processes. The resources of the process, e.g. memory and CPU time, are allocated to it via the operating system.

A thread is a so called lightweight process. It has its own call stack, but can access shared data of other threads in the same process. Every thread has its own memory cache. If a thread reads shared data it stores this data in its own memory cache. A thread can re-read the shared data.

A Java application runs by default in one process. Within a Java application you work with several threads to achieve parallel processing or asynchronous behavior.

Example
Here is an example that creates a new thread and starts running it −

```
class RunnableDemo implements Runnable {
   private Thread t;
   private String threadName;

   RunnableDemo( String name) {
      threadName = name;
      System.out.println("Creating " +  threadName );
   }

   public void run() {
      System.out.println("Running " +  threadName );
      try {
         for(int i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println("Thread: " + threadName + ", " + i);
            // Let the thread sleep for a while.
            Thread.sleep(50);
         }
      }catch (InterruptedException e) {
         System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " interrupted.");
      }
      System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " exiting.");
   }

   public void start () {
      System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
      if (t == null) {
         t = new Thread (this, threadName);
         t.start ();
      }
   }
}

public class TestThread {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      RunnableDemo R1 = new RunnableDemo( "Thread-1");
      R1.start();

      RunnableDemo R2 = new RunnableDemo( "Thread-2");
      R2.start();
   }   
}
```

This will produce the following result −

Output

```
Creating Thread-1
Starting Thread-1
Creating Thread-2
Starting Thread-2
Running Thread-1
Thread: Thread-1, 4
Running Thread-2
Thread: Thread-2, 4
Thread: Thread-1, 3
Thread: Thread-2, 3
Thread: Thread-1, 2
Thread: Thread-2, 2
Thread: Thread-1, 1
Thread: Thread-2, 1
Thread Thread-1 exiting.
Thread Thread-2 exiting.
```

[1] http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html

[2] https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm

Comment: Thanks Phoenix. I guess threads still run within the single OS process. However the text states "APIs that allow programs to use many operating-system processes" . Is this true?

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: Does each thread translate to a OS process? I was assuming all the threads share the same OS process

Comment: No, one process can have multiple threads. Please refer to the referenced links for detailed explanation.

Comment: Sure , I'll have a look. So if one process is associated with multiple threads , how is this statement true "allow programs to use many operating-system processes (hence, many “cores”) at the same time". Does JVM process use multiple OS processes?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `ProcessBuilder` class. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

> Each ProcessBuilder instance manages a collection of process attributes. The start() method creates a new Process instance with those attributes.

You can also create multiple network processes in Java server(UNIX based OS only) using `Akuma`.

Follow this link: http://akuma.kohsuke.org